# declaring variables in abstract parent class or interface

Tags: java, variables, interface, abstract-class

when i am running a simple code with the help of abstract class or interface, while compiling the main method, it asks me to mandatorily define a instance variable in parent abstract class (or interface) even when I may have defined & even initialised it using constructor in the child class. On top of it, it just fixes the variable value if I define it in parent class (or interface) i.e. it is making it mandatory for me to define a variable and then treating it as 'static' 'final'. I am compling it using eclipse. What mistake would I be making if any.

I read through other forum that if one defines a variable in interface it is automatically treated as final. so, it explains part of above but then why should it be mandatory to define in parent and why it should also be there in abstract class.

please help. thanks.

Comment: There is no way to make a sub-class define a field/variable, and there  is no such error which says you must define a variable in a sub-class, or class implementing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable in an interface, it automatically becomes a public, static and final, and you need to assign it a value in the definition of the interface itself:

```
public interface myInterface {
    int myInteger = 10; // public static final by implication.
}
```